# Will a USB powered fan cool my Pi 3 with a touchscreen attached and will it draw to much power?

Tags: pi-3, cooling

I have seen tutorials that show a fan plugged into the USB port to cool the Pi, would this overload the Pi? Is it necessary to use a fan at all?

Comment: I am trying to work this out on my own. Temperature doesnt seem to be as much of a problem as I thought. However the screen uses a ton of CPU, and occasionally I get a warning. I stopped using the screen for now while i gather more information

Comment: Welcome to this Q&A - Please can you try and organise your question a little bit better. I am having difficulty understanding what you are asking. Please read it again as if somebody was trying to ask you this question. For example, you say running of the PINS.. which PINS? THere are 50 pins on the Pi. Why does the LCD drive CPU so high anyway? What is a 3.5v recharge? Are you concerned about damage due to overheat or are you asking how to wire the fan? Its very unclear.. Please just read over it again and explain better. Thanks +1 for joining and asking your first question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking a cooling fan is not required for the safe operation of a Raspberry Pi.

The cooling fan would probably plug into the GPIO or USB, I've used a fan that is rated at 5V and 0.2A with my Pi 2. It reduced the temperature slightly but not significantly. Certainly not significant enough to warrant the noise the fan produced.

The Pi has a thermal limit of 85°C, when it reaches this temperature it will limit the performance of the CPU to reduce the temperature.

I think it is unlikely that you will ever reach this temperature unless you are either doing some serious overclocking or running the CPU at 100% for sustained periods of time.

If you do want to use a cooling fan make sure the Pi is adequately powered. You need to use a power supply that can reliably deliver 5V at 2A. Also to improve the cooling performance you could add a heatsink to the SoC and the Ethernet controller. Since these are the two chips on the board that tend to get the hottest.

Comment: I have  ordered the heat sinks already. I have the temp set on my panel already it is usually never running hotter than 80 max. I am not over clocked and keep an eye on my CPU. Thanks for adding your personal experience I never considered the noise factor.